# Получаю с сервера потоком PDF, как задать имя и URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf

Получаю с сервера потоком `pdf`, отображаю в новом окне. Как сделать нормальное имя файла при сохранении - `document.pdf`, и чтоб в строке адреса был нормальный URL - `"api/mmm/document.pdf`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', 'api/mmm/', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
var params = JSON.stringify(rz);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([this.response], {
                type: 'application/pdf'
            }),
            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        window.open(url);
    }
};
xhr.send(params);
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454432/178988